Flushed clay cat litter once
As the title says… In a moment of lapse in judgement, I tried flushing cat litter this morning.  I did it at my family member’s house while cat sitting.
I immediately got my hands dirty and scooped all of it out.
Everything seems fine and I scooped out all (or at least most) of it.  I used a long foldable brush to make sure I cleaned the curves. Also used my gloved hands to touch all the corners I could reach (incredibly grim).
The toilet is flushing as usual. No problems at all.
However, I’m freaking out.  I’m worried it might cause problems in the future.
Do you think it should be fine or should I do something more?

Either it clogs, or it doesn't.

I'd tell the homeowner, assuming that they are friends. (If you're cat sitting commercially, maybe not...) But all you can do is either hope that other semi-solids eventually pick up and remove whatever hit through, or wait for a clog and snake or disassemble at that time. As they say, shit happens..

Not to worry. Each time you flush, more of the clay is washed out. Since it already works, it will only get cleaner with time. BTW, you have my sympathy, scooping out that waste.
